# how to assign a string to a fixed sized char array

Tags: c, string, char

I am reading a string from a json object. The string can be compressed or uncompressed. If it's compressed, I have to decompress it. So depending on the compressed condition I want to assign a value to with [json_string_value](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.11/apiref.html#c.json_string_value). I know the size of the string, hence I want the string to have a static size.

I have the following:

```
char my_string[MY_SIZE];

if( [some condition]){ 
    //how to assign a value to my_string in this case?
} else {
    ...
    int ret = decompress(compressed_str, compressed_str_len, my_string, MY_SIZE);
    ...
}
```

`json_string_value()` returns a string with a null terminator.

I managed to get it to work by using a different string literal and copying the value over

```
const char *tmp = json_string_value(image);
strcpy(my_string, tmp);
```

but I was wondering if there is an easier (better) way to do this?

Comment: Where do you have a string literal? String literals are in double quotes, e.g. `"foo"`

Comment: @Barmar: right, sorry, mixed up names. And sorry again, used the wrong variable names, edited my answer

Comment: Slightly off-topic: beware buffer overrun when you use `strcpy`. Consider `strncpy` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all the extra variables, you can just call the function in `strcpy()` arguments.

```
strcpy(my_string, json_string_value(image));
```

Comment: " I know the size of the string" I would still strncpy just in case, cant be too careful in C

Comment: If you use `strncpy()` and the length is too short you end up with an unterminated string. It prevents buffer overflow, but causes other problems. It's not a magic bullet.

Comment: TIL that strncpy_s is part of C11. So thats what should be used